# Why does this small change halt my C++ program?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to C++ trying to wrap my head around the fundamentals. This small alteration gives a subtle change in my program behaviour, preventing it's complete run. The problem is every time I arrive at the prompt to enter school, I can't input any text.

**Software Info:**

> **OS:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>
> **G++ version:** 4.8.4

**This is the code which runs fine:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string fName, DOB, school;
    int age;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "What is your name: ";
    getline (cin, fName);
    cout << "What school do you attend: ";
    getline (cin, school);
    cout << "How old are you: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << school << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**This is the code which halts:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string fName, DOB, school;
    int age;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "What is your name: ";
    getline (cin, fName);
    cout << "How old are you: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "What school do you attend: "; // this is the only change.
    getline (cin, school);
    cout << school << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The only change is moving:

```
cout << "What school do you attend: ";
        getline (cin, school);
```

from lines 13 & 14 to lines 15 & 16.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Say you entered `10` and then pressed enter; `cin >> age` will not consume the newline character. And then `getline` reads an empty line.

Comment: So how do I go around this. What's the solution?

Comment: I remember having to loop around getchar() until cin is empty. It's annoying. Sorry but can't remember more than that.

Comment: @RonThompson That's another new concept to me for now. I just want a more elaborated explanation of my issue's occurrence.

Comment: Don't mix `getline` with `>>` extraction; consistently use `getline` to read from `cin`, then use the `strto*` family of functions (from `<cstdlib>`) to convert strings to numbers.  (If you have full C++11 support you can use the [`sto*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) functions instead.)

Comment: @zwol I tried your method, including the library and `stoi (age, nullptr,2);` but that didn't work.

Comment: @CheddieMerai It should have worked. What _exactly_ did it do instead of working?

Comment: @zwol It works. Now. Took a few seconds at first to show the output. Nifty trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have said, there could be a character remaining in the input buffer, most likely the `\n` charachter when you pressed Enter.

You could add:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Right after your `cin` to get all the remaining characters in the buffer, but this is mostly for C.

In C++ you could instead:

```
std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');
```

Which will get and discard the next `256` characters it finds in the buffer or until it finds a `char` equal to the one passed as the second argument, in this case a `\n` or newline character. Note that for the second parameter, when it is found it is also discarded.

Comment: That while loop. I remember basically writing my own input library and wrapping all IO through that stupid loop so I could stop dealing with it.

Comment: @RonThompson I too remember those harsh times my friend, until C++ showed me the way of OOP :)

Comment: I used the C++ concept. Worked like the charm that it is.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Enter' after age is consumed as a character for school variable in the second program. The easiest solution is to read a dummy character( a useless variable) after reading 'age' in the second program.